# How to retrieve the properties of a NextJS Component in runtime?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, types, reflection

I have a bunch of NextJS components such as this one:

```
"use client";

type Props = {
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
};

export default function HeaderComponent(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <h2>{props.subtitle}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am trying to find a way to extract the component props in run-time to an array of names. in the case above I'm looking to get the response of:

```
["title", "subtitle"]
```

I thought I can achieve this by following the [NextJS docs on lazy loading and dynamic components](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#examples) but so far ended up with ComponentPropsType without knowing how to convert it to an array of strings. what I have so far is:

```
const Component = dynamic(() => import("../components/header"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: (lodaingProps) => {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  },
});
type ComponentPropsType = React.ComponentProps<typeof Component>;
```

Can someone please direct me on the right way to do this? at this point I'm not even sure this is feasible. based on some readings I found that this type of data may not even available in run-time. is that true?